# Заменить изображения в меню

Tags: java, android, menu

java код

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.new_deposit:
                newDepoiit();
                return true;
            case R.id.delite_deposit:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_deposit"
        android:title="@string/new_deposit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/news"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delite_deposit"
        android:title="@string/delite_deposit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/delite_on"/>
    
</menu>
```

При нажатии кнопки `delite_deposit` хочу чтобы изменилась иконка вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

1. Объявляете переменную без инициализации.

   `MenuItem menuItem;`
2. Переопределяем метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu` в котором присваиваем переменной пункт меню:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.delite_deposit);
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```
3. В вашем методе обращаетесь к пункту меню и меняете картинку, например так:

   `menuItem.setActionView(imageView);`

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего случая.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.delite_deposit:
        item.setIcon( R.drawable.delite_off);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

На практике делают отдельную функцию где по значению переменной выставляют нужную иконку при `onCreateOptionsMenu` и при нажатии/смене состояния.